# Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: yes)

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mysql-error-1045

I'd found too many questions related to this problem still I'm having the same problem.

I've installed `MySQL Server` from [MYSQL::Download MYSQL Installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/). Also, I've running `xampp` on my `localhost`.

`http://localhost/phpmyadmin` and `MySQL Command Line Client` are working fine and I'm able to login as well as execute `SQL` queries. But the problem is, if I'm using `jdbc` to connect to `MySQL` then the error comes `Access denied for 'root'@'localhost' (using password:yes)`.
The connection string I'm using for jdbc is

```
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb", "root", "root");
```

but it's not working. I tried removing the port number (3306), still the same problem.
I also tried to start `MySQL Workbench` installed with the installer and getting the same error for connection.

If anybody could help? `phpmyadmin` working fine and I'm able to run sql queries from a `php` program. But its not working fine with `java`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try granting the privileges:-

```
 mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *. * TO root@localhost

-> IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```