# Trying to run: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have compiled the files and try to run it by

```
./DBServer
```

I ended up with

```
cfg.bin: No such file or directory
Entering DBServer setup()
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have tried [the solution provided here as follows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16880877/access-denied-for-user-userlocalhost-using-password-yes)

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *. * TO root@localhost
-> IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

but no luck.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Might help to say what you're trying to do. Have you flushed privileges after changing them?

Comment: you have a space in your DB wildcard and you should escape or encapsulate the user/hostname as follows  'root'@'localhost'

Comment: @miken32 I am following a manual to install a software suite. In the previous step, I have done `sudo make` and now I run the compiled file.

Comment: @apesa  I have made it `mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *. * TO 'root'@'localhost'
-> IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass' WITH GRANT OPTION;` But it still fails.

Comment: You have a space in your DB wildcard.. *. * it should not have a space  and should look like this *.*